# Boost Thread: Use of deleted function Error

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, boost, b2

I am trying to use a multi-threading in boost to handle multiple requests and upon the reception of a specific message I will create a new thread to handle it as below:

**main.cpp**

/**
* Destination Machine Request Handler.
*
* @param msg Received message.
* @param ec Error code.
*/
void handover_request_handler(odtone::mih::message &msg, const boost::system::error_code &ec)
{
    if (ec)
    {
        log_(0, **FUNCTION**, " error: ", ec.message());
        return;
    }
    // Do some stuff
}

void event_handler(odtone::mih::message &msg, const boost::system::error_code &ec)
{
    if (ec)
    {
        log_(0, **FUNCTION**, " error: ", ec.message());
        return;
    }

`switch (msg.mid())
{
    // Destination Cloud Server received HO Commit Message
    case odtone::mih::indication::n2n_ho_commit:
    {
        boost::thread thrd(boost::bind(&handover_request_handler,  msg, ec));
        thrd.join();
    }
    break;
     }`

}

When I try to compile it using b2 tool, I get the following errors:

**gcc.compile.c++ ../../bin.v2/app/lte_mih_usr/gcc-4.6/debug/link-static/runtime-link-static/main.o
main.cpp: In function ‘void event_handler(odtone::mih::message&, const boost::system::error_code&)’:
main.cpp:189:69: error: use of deleted function ‘odtone::mih::message::message(const odtone::mih::message&)’
In file included from ../../inc/odtone/mih/request.hpp:24:0,
                 from main.cpp:11:**

So how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `thread` constructor copies its arguments, and the `message` type is not copyable.  To pass a reference to the target function you need to use `boost::ref(msg)`

Also note that using `bind` with `thread` is unnecessary:

```
boost::thread thrd(&handover_request_handler, boost::ref(msg), boost::ref(ec));
```

The `thread` constructor implements the same semantics as `bind`, so using `bind` just adds unnecessary additional copying.